# Eclipse java application heap size cannot exceed 4G

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I need to run an application with -Xmx12g but I cannot get 12g in eclipse.

I can run it fine from terminal directly, `java -Xmx12g ...` which shows me the max memory as 12G from this command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Running same thing in eclipse, as runtime vm parameters, I get 4G max. I tried maxing values in eclipse.ini(which should not affect my java application right?), no change.
I have 16G ram, my friend has 64G, he can run it fine but I can't get more than 4g with same settings. I'm not getting any error or anything.
64 bit os, 64 bit vm

Comment: what happens when you set it to 2G?  you may be editing the settings in the wrong place..

Comment: @ChrisK I still got 4g and it immediately reminded me a change I did couple years ago... Eclipse preferences JRE had default VM arguments: -Xmx4g which was overriding run configuration. It would make more sense if it was other way but anyway, it's solved now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. There is a default VM arguments part for each JRE, which was causing everything to run in 4G for me, even though I try to override -Xmx in Run Configuration